# TypeError: different number of components either side of equation

Tags: arrays, erc-721

I am working on a project using ERC721. Code below

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
contract Sketch is ERC721 {
  string[] public sketchs;
  mapping(string => bool) _sketchExists;
  constructor() ERC721("Sketch", "SKETCH") public {
  }
  function mint(string memory _sketch) public {
    uint _id = sketchs.push(_sketch);
    _mint(msg.sender, _id);
    _sketchExists[_sketch] = true;
  }
}
```

But when I truffle migrate I get a TypeError "Different number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (0)". Because uint _id has 1 and sketchs has 0

```
uint _id = sketchs.push(_sketch);
```

Is that because my **sketchs** array starts at 0? If that is the case how would I initialize this then? Any direction/assistance would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Operation `push` has changed behavior since since solidity 0.6. It no longer returns the length but a reference to the added element.

You can solve this by splitting the assignment in two operations:

```
sketchs.push(_sketch);
uint _id = sketchs.length - 1;
```